# Using nested [ ] operations for std::vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I am quite new to C++, and i have tried searching for an answer to this and running tests, but many times I'm having trouble figuring out what causes specific behaviors. 
My question relates to using nested `[ ]` operators to access or modify elements in a loop - example:

```cpp
//Declare

std::vector<int> a1 {10,20,30,40} ;
std::vector<int> a2 {2,3} ;
int S2 = a2.size() ; 

//Loop
for(int i = 0 ; i < S2 ; i++){
         a1[a2[i]] = a1[a2[i]] + 5000 ;
}
```

Is this considered ok? I'm asking not only in terms of common practice, but also in terms of efficiency and any other potential factor I need to consider. 
Am I supposed to first store `a[i]` inside a temporary variable inside the loop and then use it to modify my element in vector `a2`?

I do know that its probably not the best structure and I should be using some other data structure to do this kind of thing, but I just want to understand if this is ok or if it might cause some undefined behavior.

Comment: This works as posted, but it relies on the untold assumption that each element in `a2` is non-negative and less than the size of `a1`. The line in the loop could also be written using `+=` though any self respecting compiler will generate the same code regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perfectly correct.

But in fact, you just want to iterate the elements of a standard container. C++ allows the *range based for statement* for that use case:

```
for (index: a2) {
    a1[index] += 5000;
}
```

I find it more readable even if it is mainly a matter of taste...

Disclaimer: this code makes no control of the validity of the elements of `a2` as index of `a1`.

Comment: In terms of the final result, will this compile to be more efficient than my standard for loop? I really like your method as it reminds me of R subsetting methods.

Comment: @dvd280 The compiler will implement the range based for loop with a traditional for loop. That means that your code and Serge's will compile to identical binaries, which will perform identically.

Answer (score 6):

I am developer for a finite element calculation software.

We use this technique in order to access the values inside an element. It helps us to save a lot of memory

BUT: Be aware that it spoils your cache locality. Don't use it in heavy loops, if you can avoid it.

If you need a range checks and performance is not important, you can consider using the `at` operator of the `std::vector`

```
 for(const auto & index :a2) {
      a1.at(index) += 5000;
 }
```

The `at` function automatically checks whether n is within the bounds of valid elements in the vector, throwing an out_of_range exception if it is not (i.e., if n is greater than, or equal to, its size). This is in contrast with member operator[], that does not check against bounds.

Moreover, consider using a range based loop

```
 //Loop
 for(const auto & index :a2) {
      a1[index] += 5000;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks okay to me. There is no need to create an explicit copy of `a2[i]`.

The only issue I see with something like this is that the argument inside `[]` should be of type `std::size_t` instead of `int`. These integer types encompass different ranges of values, and while `std::size_t` is an unsigned integer type, `int` is a signed integer. Beware of using negative indexes or indexes past the last element will likely result in undefined behavior due to out-of-bounds access. But if you can guarantee that the values in `a2` are always valid indexes for `a1`, then these `int` values will implicitly be converted to `std::size_t` and things works properly (which seems to be the case in the code example in your question).

I also suggest to convert the loop variable `i` to `std::size_t` (and use `++i` instead of `i++` if you want to be perfect:).

In modern C++, you can also use a range-based for so you don't have use an explicit index variable for accessing `a2` values at all:

```cpp
for (auto indexFromA2 : a2)
    a1[indexFromA2] += 5000;
```

This is less error-prone, because you have to write less logic for managing the element access (and don't have to spell out the types).

Answer (score 1):

I would somehow ensure that the elements in `a1` defined in `a2` do really exist before trying to access them, otherwise you run out of bounds.

But in regards of nested `[]` this is fine and there's no need to create another copy of `a2` to access `a1`. The compiler is just unwrapping your expression from inside out.

You can still simplify your code a bit

```
 //Declare
 std::vector<int> a1 {10,20,30,40} ;
 std::vector<int> a2 {2,3} ;

 //Loop
 for(int i = 0 ; i < a2.size() ; i++){
          if(a1.size()-1 < a2[i]){break;}
          a1[a2[i]] += 5000 ;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, In my case a bound check will not be necessary as I'm directly calculating all elements in `a2` prior to inserting them , such that non valid indices are filtered out before their entry to the vector.